# Am I going to have problems if I try to use classes I wrote using jdk7 on jdk6?

Tags: java, compatibility, java-7

I do plan to check the API and make sure that I am only using jdk6 libraries but a couple of compatibility posts on here have made me a bit nervous.

I need to upload some files onto a jdk6 computer but I run eclipse with jdk7 on mine and I do not have time to check if the files will compile. I need them to be able to compile. Is there something I can do to avoid trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse, use the JDK compliance property. Right click on a project, Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level -> 1.6

Comment: In eclipse, use the JDK compliance property. Right click on a project, Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level -> 1.6

and that is it? I don't need to install jdk6? That is a relief. I won't be able to say whether it works or not yet though so I hope you are right!

Comment: Yes that's it. Internally, this will set the -target argument of the javac executable to 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-target` key for java 1.7 compiler to make sure your code will run on jvm 6 flawlessly.